# Creating an Azure AD app using az powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to create an azure AD app and a client secret for that app. In the end: the code should print App-ID, tenant ID, and value of client secret:
here is the code that I have written:

```
# Function to generate a random password
function Generate-Password {
    $validChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+"
    $password = ""
    For ($i=0; $i -lt 16; $i++) {
        $random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum $validChars.Length
        $password += $validChars[$random]
    }
    return $password
}

# Authenticate and login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Set the name, home page URL, and identifier URI of the app
$appName = "test-123"

# Generate a random password for the client secret
$clientSecretPassword = Generate-Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# Create the Azure AD app
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

# Create a client secret for the app
$secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -Password $clientSecretPassword

$secret.Secret

# Print the Client ID and Tenant ID of the app
Write-Host "Client ID: " $app.ApplicationId
Write-Host "Tenant ID: " (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id

# Print the value of the client secret
$clientsecret =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.Secret))
Write-Host "Client Secret: " $clientSecret
```

but I am getting the following error for this:

```
Exception calling "SecureStringToBSTR" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s"
At C:\Users\azure-app.ps1:35 char:1
+ $clientsecret =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStrin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
 
Client Secret:
```

Can anyone help me debug this issue or re-factor the code?
Thank you

Comment: Is the variable secrete null?  type the command to get secrete and see if it has a value.  In most windows system username password no longer works and you must use a credential.

Comment: I am creating password for client secret, not for login.

Comment: It should be -PasswordCredentials  (not password).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?force_isolation=true&view=azps-9.4.0

Comment: Try something like  `$credentials = New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $App.Id -StartDate $start -EndDate $end `
`Write-host "The new password is $($credentials.SecretText) (Please note this as you will not be able to access it afterwards) "  `

Comment: Hi, both of the above solution are not printing the client secret value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create an azure AD app and display the client secret & client ID using PowerShell**

You can use below **PowerShell** Script to create **Azure AP App** with **Client Secret**.

```
#Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD

#Set variables for the app
$appName = "MyApp"
$replyUrls = "http://localhost"
$secret = "MySecret"

#Create the app
$app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -ReplyUrls $replyUrls -PublicClient $false

#Create the client secret
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($secret)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)
$secret = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "MyCustomKeyIdentifier" -Value $base64 -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate

#Retrieve the tenant ID
$tenantId = (Get-AzureADTenantDetail).ObjectId

#Print the App-ID, tenant ID, and client secret
Write-Host "App-ID: $($app.AppId)"
Write-Host "Tenant ID: $tenantId"
Write-Host "Client Secret: $($secret.Value)"
```

Once ran the above commands **Azure App** got created successfully with **client secret**.

[image]

When I check **Azure App** in portal, it got created successfully.

[image]